# how to get json data using ajax in cross domain

Tags: json, jquery, cross-browser

I have to dynamically get data from another domain dynamically and I want to use ajax and jquery.I have done the following.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#getdata').click(function(){
            var sitename = $('#sitename').val();
            var listname = $('#listname').val();
            getdata(sitename, listname);
        })
    });
   function getdata(sitename, listname){
$.ajax({
            url : 'http://192.168.10.34:8576/home/GetJsonData?site='+sitename+'&listname='+listname+'&viewname=',
            datatype : 'JSON',
            type : 'GET',
            crossDomain: true,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success : function(data){

                console.log(data)
            },
            error : function(){
                alert('error');
            }
        })
}
</script>
```

But it's just returning error. why? Have I done anything wrong?
any help/suggestions are welcome. thanks.

Comment: Is that domain implementing CORS?

Comment: whether the application in `http://192.168.10.34:8576/` supports cross domain requests (CORS)

Comment: if not think about implementing CORS or JSONP

Answer (score 0):

You cannot request data from any domain other than the domain from where your JavaScript has originated from. For cases like this you should use JSONP(JSON with Padding). Change the dataType to JSONP in jQuery ajax function. Like this...

```
datatype : 'JSONP'
```

Also, your cross domain(`http://192.168.10.34:8576/home/GetJsonData`) should support jsonp or else your request will fail.

Comment: If he has control over the application, he may be better off avoiding the JSONP hack and just implementing CORS

Comment: But since he is already using jQuery it is a simple change provided the other domain supports it.

Comment: If he's only issuing GET requests, then sure. If he's issuing POSTs anywhere, then he can't just use JSONP

Answer (score 0):

The alternative to using the JSONP hack is to allow for Cross-Origin Resource Sharing on your application.

It's painfully simple to handle this, but understand that this opens up minor to intermediate security issues at scale, so make sure to take care of them appropriately.

Simply set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header in your server application to `*`. CORS requests also issue `OPTIONS` preflight requests, so you can choose whether or not to handle those as well.